# Cannot upload mp4 file to my mediawiki site

Tags: php, mediawiki

can not upload mp4 file to my mediawiki site.

when i upload mp4 file, it show this error:

[image: error msg]

have searched google for the error msg "Exception caught: No specifications provided to ArchivedFile constructor", found nothing useful.

i have enabled upload and allow mp4 filetype, this is my LocalSettings :

```
$wgEnableUploads = true;
...
$wgFileExtensions = array_merge( $wgFileExtensions,
    array( 'mp4')
);
```

Comment: How big is the file? Can you try with a small one? (Maybe this is a chunked uploading error.) This also looks like you're using the uploader of the WikiEditor toolbar; do you get the same error when uploading via Special:Upload?

Comment: @feiffy Did you ever solve this? I'm just trying to get local mp4 uploads to work.

Answer (score 0):

I use **Youtube** MediaWiki extension for uploading videos to the localhosted MediaWiki version 1.27. It is a stable extension. You can download this exxtension from https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:YouTube

On TinyMCE, I use it as follows:

1) Login to MediaWiki.
2) Go to WikiMagic in a dropdown menu.
3) Suppose the video link is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VyBSS48E4xI, so in the WikiMagic Editor, simply add `<youtube>VyBSS48E4xI</youtube>`.

When you save your changes, the video appears on the Article page.

**PS:** I have tried this only with TinyMCE editor and it works fine. I should also work for VisualEditor, CKEditor and Bluespice as well